# Android device connects to my computer, but doesn't play audio over Bluetooth

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, android, bluetooth

I turn on Bluetooth on both my devices and open up Music on my Android. I select a song to play, press the menu button, and tap "Via Bluetooth":

[image: Menu with "Via Bluetooth" pressed]

I tap on my computer in the "Bluetooth Device Picker":

[image: Bluetooth device picker]

Then it says, under the name of my computer:

> Connected to media audio

Now I should *technically* be able to play music through my computer, since it "Just Worked" in **Kubuntu** with Blueman. But nope, something must be up with PulseAudio, because I hear no sound from my computer (I'm running **Xubuntu** 12.04). The reason I say this is that the devices list in Blueman shows indication of data transfer and it *says* it's connected, but in the PulseAudio Volume Control has ***no*** indication of my Bluetooth device (or Blueman) playing audio.

Comment: I have tried that few times and each time I have failed. I could never make my Bluetooth work correctly on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah... And I saw the way they were saying on the wiki to set up a headset. Waaaaaaaay too complicated.  I wish that things would "Just Work".

Comment: Install an application called listen on ubuntu. On android if you play audio and if it shows bluetooth (e.g when changing volume), you are good to go. On ubuntu in listen select the bluetooth device name, to hear sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I figured out:

Either

1. Remove PulseAudio and then install a mixer such as `xfce4-mixer`.
2. Install the package `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`.

Then it should "Just Work."

Answer (score 1):

You should install bluez-audio and blueman . and it will work

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking to connect phone and stream audio to ubuntu system via bluetooth,

Install `d-feet`

```
sudo apt-get install d-feet
```

- Pair your phone via bluetooth,
- Open d-feet, filter and find `org.bluez` (ref pic below), locate your
  phone in the list,
- Open `Inferfaces > org.bluez.AudioSource > Methods`
- Double-click on "Connect"
- Click on "Execute" in the dialog that opens.

[image]

Ref: http://blog.stevenocchipinti.com/2012/10/bluetooth-audio-streaming-from-phone-to.html/
Ref: https://ricardojlrufino.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/bluetooth-audio-from-phone-to-ubuntu/